# Is it fine to use block() in spring reactor tests for test state creation?

Tags: junit, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-test

I'm writing integration tests using Spring, JUnit 5, JOOQ, TestContainers and Project Reactor. I want to test my repository layer, e.g. verify
`Mono<Entity> get(Long id)` method.

Therefore, my test should first create entity in database and then verify, that this entity exists. There are two approaches how to do it

1. Do everything in non-blocking way, e.g.

```
@Test
public void testGetById() {
    var entityPojo = new EntityPojo().setName(UUID.randomUUID());
    entityRepository.create(entityPojo)
        .zipWhen(e -> entityRepository.get(e.getId()))
        .as(StepVerifier::create)
        .assertNext(t -> assertThat(t.getT1()).isEqualTo(t.getT2()))
        .verifyComplete();
}
```

2. Block on create() method

```
@Test
public void testGetById() {
    var entityPojo = new EntityPojo().setName(UUID.randomUUID());
    var entity = entityRepository.create(entityPojo).block();
    entityRepository.get(e.getId())
        .as(StepVerifier::create)
        .assertNext(e -> assertThat(e).isEqualTo(entity))
        .verifyComplete();
}
```

Are there any best practices on this? I would prefer second approach, because it's more readable, but may be there are cons of doing it this way, which I'm not aware of?

Comment: if you use only for test porpoise to make your test more easy to write or read you are good to go

Comment: Yes, this is only about tests. Thank you!